# Unhandled exception: invalid column Comment for resultset issue in mysql-wordbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

When i click on schema inspector in context menu for one particular database from mysql-workbench then i keep getting below error.
**Unhandled exception: invalid column Comment for resultset**

Few details about my OS and Mysql-workbench
**OS**  : Linux ubuntu 12.04 LTS
**Mysql-workbench-community**
Version : 6.1.4

Please help so that i can proceed with my work.

**EDIT 1**
FYI, When i inspect schema for other database, It inspect well without any error message.

Comment: "Generate scheme inspector" doesn't make sense. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @MikeLischke : I edited my question, As schema inspector option in context menu giving such problem. So when i click on schema inspector i get the mentioned error message.

Comment: That might be due to a bug, but version 6.1.4 is rather old. We fix bugs constantly, so try the latest release (6.2.3 at the time begin) and see if that problem is solved there.

Comment: @MikeLischke I dont mean to hijack the question, I think I have a similar issue but the error I get is "SystemError: DbMySQLQuery.resultNextRow(): Invalid resultset" in OSX with version 6.2.3, should I open a new question or do you have any advise for me?

Comment: First try the latest version (a new one is due soon).

Comment: I have this same issue.  I seem to only have it on databases that have tables with Comments (as per "Alter Table").  Currently using 6.2.5.0 (b397)